How to enable/start monitors on Debian 12
I'm using a Debian 12 with the original Nvidia Driver.  Now, I have three "Monitors", one being the build in of the Laptop I'm using. The middle one works, the others don't. They are not recognized in the System Setting and the Nvidia Settings.


The Output of xandr is the following

I've tried activating them one by one with
xrandr --output DP-0 --auto
But nothing worked.

What are the outputs of of xrandr --listproviders and lspci -d ::0300?


xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0


lspci -d ::0300
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)
Sorry for the bad Structure, it didn't let me Structure the Comment well.


In the comments, you said the lspci -d ::0300 output was:
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 630 (rev 04) 
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile] (rev a1)

indicating that your system has two GPUs: the CPU-integrated Intel GPU (iGPU for short) and the NVIDIA discrete GPU (dGPU for short), and the xrandr --listproviders output was:
Providers: number : 1 
Provider 0: id: 0x1b7 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0

indicating that only the NVIDIA GPU is currently being used.
The problem
You have a dual-GPU laptop: NVIDIA calls this Optimus Technology. Unfortunately, the most common implementation of this does not include a multiplexer switch that would allow either GPU a physical connection to each display output connector. This is known as "muxless Optimus". When using a combination of display connections that are not directly wired to the active GPU, the missing connections must be substituted by passing rendered output data from one GPU to the other, which can then output the data to the displays it's physically connected to.
In laptops, a common muxless Optimus solution is as follows:

the laptop's own display and VGA output is wired to the iGPU (allowing power-efficient operation when no external displays are available, or when using the VGA output for presentation on a video projector)
any digital display outputs such as HDMI and/or DisplayPort are usually wired to the dGPU, for maximum performance when connected to external desktop display (and presumably external power supply is readily available, so being economical with battery power is not an issue).

In your specific case, it seems that only the HDMI output of the NVIDIA GPU chip is actually wired to a physical output connector.
The solution
First, you should ensure that you have the xserver-xorg-video-intel package installed. It contains the X11 driver for your Intel iGPU, which is required even just to pass display data through it. That driver, in turn, requires that the kernel module 'i915' is loaded, and that any firmware files it requires are present, i.e. the firmware-misc-nonfree package is installed.
Then, you should make a backup of your current /etc/X11/xorg.conf file (if it exists), and then change it to contain the following (creating the file if it doesn't exist):
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

(This configuration snippet is directly from the NVIDIA GPU driver README file, with the BusID for your hardware already written in.)
This will tell the X server to start both drivers (even if no displays seem to be connected), and tell it to use the NVIDIA GPU as the primary one.
With modern enough version of the Xorg X server, this alone might be enough to make your extra displays available for use.
But if not, you might need two commands to explicitly feed display data from NVIDIA GPU to the Intel one:
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto

The first command tells the Intel GPU base driver (modesetting) to act as extra outputs for display data whose source is the NVIDIA GPU.
The second command makes the X server activate any displays that might have become available as the result of the previous command.
If you find the two xrandrcommands are needed, you could automate the process by writing them into e.g. /etc/X11/Xsession.d/92custom_xrandr.

The xorg.conf setting that you have been given me are working perfectly fine, thank you a lot. Very interesting Problem.

If the xrandr command does not yield the external monitor you are intending to use, my experience teaches me that there is something wrong with the external monitor jack/port connectivity. I usually have to tie the monitor cable with a rubber band or weigh it down with some books until the pins can connect correctly. I'm using a laptop that is more than 5 years old, which VGA and HDMI ports are getting rusty by days.

With using Windows or no Nvidia Driver they work perfectly, so I don't think it's that.
